# Java 8 Lambda Consuming using numerous times a piece of information with one iteration

Tags: java, lambda, consumer, consuming

I build a small example to test the java 8.
Having a list of Strings:

`List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Sheep", "Ship","Skeleton" });`

The following function:

```
list.stream().forEach(name -> list.forEach(name2->System.out.println("Name2:"+name2+" name:" + name + "=>" + name2.compareTo(name))));
```

returns the comparison between name2 and name1.

I am trying to test and I don't know if it is feasible this scenario:
Having the same list and an independent String variable called `lastFoundWord`
can I assign with a "lambda way" the variable just right after the comparison as it happens with the previous line ?

**Note**:I see that forEach can not accept a list of Consumers, and Consumer building is very strict. I am not sure about the "Function" interface.
All my thought directs me to iterate twice the same information.

Is there perhaps a forEach function that accepts a list of Consumers and I missed it ?

Comment: could you not create a consumer that would dispatch to  all the consumers you need to?

Comment: Would you mean something like Consumer<List<Consumer<String>>> class ?

Comment: That or you could do on your list of consumers: `list.stream().reduce((a,b) -> a.andThen(b))` to produce a single consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Using consumers from a list is something I try to figure.

Although for my current example, I found a solution using braces.
So the code turned to that:

```
list.stream().forEach(name -> list.forEach(name2 -> {
    System.out.println("Name2:" + name2 + " name:" + name + "=>" + name2.compareTo(name));
    lastName = name2;
}));
```